# How do I get the --watch flag to work on OSX command line?

Tags: macos, kubernetes, terminal, posix

I'm attempting to watch my Kubernetes deployment spin up by using the `kubectl get deploy <name> --watch` on the command line on my MacBook. The output just returns the number of seconds that have occurred, but no actual information from the command.

[image: --watch flag output]

Is there something I need to be doing differently on OSX to get this command to work? Same results across all terminal programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of argument --watch is just watching the status changes like you said. If you want to see the logs of your command and following it, use this command:

```
kubectl logs -l app=[your_deployment_name] --follow
```